# content editor on share point online site

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-editor-web-part

my company disabled the costume script from the admin tenant, and I cannot find the content editor on my (team template ) share point online site, So My question is: Is there any workaround solution or steps how to find the content Editor

Comment: What exactly is your requirement you need Content Editor for? Maybe there can be a different way to look at the problem, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, there is no Content Editor web part in SharePoint Online. I suggest you try and work with web parts available to you or start with SPFx development - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/overview-client-side-web-parts

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the content editor or script editor web part in SharePoint online - we must enable the custom scripting in the admin center. Please see the below:

- Allow users from running custom script on personal sites. Allow users
- from running custom script on self-service created sites)

[image: Allow Custom Script in SharePoint Online]

If you just enable the above setting - it will not be enabled, we have to run the below PowerShell command:

```
$adminUserID=”youradminaccount@< sprnd.onmicrosoft.com >”

$userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUserID -Message “Enter password”

Connect-SPOService -Url https://sprnd-admin.sharepoint.com/ -Credential $userCredential

Set-SPOsite “https://sprnd.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite001″ -DenyAddAndCustomizePages 0
```

For details refer to the below article:

[SharePoint Online – O365: How to enable script editor web part in SharePoint online](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/how-to-enable-script-editor-web-part-in-sharepoint-online-site/)

Notes:

- If you just want to enable for time being to see the content editor web part, you can follow the above steps, then you can disable it but it admin right.
- Or in the long run, you can look at the **SPFx modern script editor** web part from here - [Add The Script Editor Webpart back to SharePoint Modern Experience](https://medium.com/niftit-sharepoint-blog/add-the-script-editor-webpart-back-to-sharepoint-modern-experience-688a7b7208e4)